# regex match string starting at offset

Tags: regex, rust

I'm learning Rust and trying to write a simple tokenizer right now. I want to go through a string running each regular expression against the current position in the string, create a token, then skip ahead and repeat until I've processed the whole string. I know I can put them into a larger regex and loop through captures, but I need to process them individually for domain reseasons.

However, I see nowhere in the regex crate that allows an offset so I can begin matching again at specific point.

```
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {

    let input = "3 + foo/4";

    let ident_re = Regex::new("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*").unwrap();
    let number_re = Regex::new("[1-9][0-9]*").unwrap();
    let ops_re = Regex::new(r"[+-*/]").unwrap();
    let ws_re = Regex::new(r"[ \t\n\r]*").unwrap();

    let mut i: usize = 0;

    while i < input.len() {

        // Here check each regex to see if a match starting at input[i]
        // if so copy the match and increment i by length of match.
    }
}
```

Those regexs that I'm currently scaning for will actually vary at runtime too. Sometimes I may only be looking for a few of them while others (at top level) I might be looking for almost all of them.

Comment: What's the "specific point"? "After each character" is what regex already does with the exception of a single part of string matching a regex multiple times as it jumps over a matched part. Is that what you're wanting to do? e.g. the same letter-number `aa9` combination matches once but could match 2 times (`aa9`, `a9`) for the first regex, if you want to check it after each character.

Comment: I think the issue is that he wants to match a few regexi in a specific order, and begin at the first regex again after a regex matched

Comment: @AndrisLeduskrasts I want to try and match a group of regexs in a certain order and when I find a match, save away the matched position information and then next time I try to match again, start at the end of the last match so I'm not constantly re-scanning the beginning of the string.

Comment: Why not clone the string (to prevent data loss) and then after each match you also substitute the match with `''`?

Comment: @AndrisLeduskrasts Performance. If I didn't care about performance I'd use another language.

Comment: I created a strscan library for this purpose exactly (tokenizing with regexes). You can check it out here: https://github.com/luke-gru/rs_strscan/, or 'strscan' on crates.io.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex crate works on string slices. You can always take a sub-slice of another slice and then operate on that one. Instead of moving along indices, you can modify the variable that points to your slice to point to your subslice.

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = "hello";
    while !s.is_empty() {
        println!("{}", s);
        s = &s[1..];
    }
}
```

Note that the slice operation slices at byte-positions, not utf8-char-positions. This allows the slicing operation to be done in O(1) instead of O(n), but will also cause the program to panic if the indices you are slicing from and to happen to be in the middle of a multi-byte utf8 character.

Comment: I'm basically trying to think of what I would want the C compiler to do and trying to get Rust to do the same thing. So this would be the rust equivalent of bumping the char* passed into function? I'll try it. I hope that the constant convertion to and from str <-> String doesn't kill the performance.

Comment: to convert from `String` to `str` is a no-op, to convert from a `str` to a `String` is a heap allocation, but I don't see where a `str` -> `String` conversion should happen in your code

Comment: isn't the "&s" an implicit convertion to &String? Or else the indexing wouldn't work since 'str's cannot be indexed, no?

Comment: you are mis-reading what's going on. it's `&(s[1..])`. We slice the string (not indexing) from position 1 to the end of the string. and then take a reference to that slice

Comment: Thanks. Weird that you cannot plainly index a str but you can slice [n .. n+1]! There really should be an 8-bit array version of str for ASCII strings since we still do most processing in that character set, astr or something. Having to be hamstrung with variable width encoding when I don't use it really sucks.

Comment: This also doesn't play well with the regex library! Regex returns positions in BYTES, but the slice uses UTF character positions, so this doesn't work actually.

Comment: yes it does. the slice uses byte positions. That's why there is no indexing operation. the "am I indexing by chars or by bytes?" question is too confusing. Note that indexing by chars would require O(n) operations, where indexing by bytes takes O(1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82565/discussion-between-ker-and-jasonn).